# Find Links in HTML Document using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

This is a challenge for any Javascript/jQuery ninjas out there:

**What is the best way (using aforementioned languages), to find all of the links in an HTML document and return them all?**

In other words, a function that like this - **findLinks(document.html.innerHTML)** that would return all links found in that HTML.

Thanks,

DLiKS

Comment: Only `<a>` tag's href or plain text that is formated like URL also?

Comment: `document.html.innerHTML`? So obliterate a traversable DOM in favor of its html string representation that you then have to parse?

Comment: @Cres: God forbid the OP might want to pass other HTML strings to the function... :-)

Comment: Any references to other URLs are links - so the links to external CSS and JS files need to be found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could fiddle around with a chunky library (and it might be a good idea to do that if you end up wanting to do interesting things to manipulate the results), but just to get the links I think I'd stick to DOM 0:

```
document.links
```

Comment: @Crescent: You're very welcome, it's always nice to see a fan :-)

Comment: WWAET? (What Would Andy E Think?)

Answer (score 2):

To get all *hrefs* from existing anchor elements, you can do the following, which will return them as an array:

```
var links = $("a").map(function() {
                return this.href;
            }).get();
```

If you just want to grab each anchor element and do something with them thereafter, you would just need to select them:

```
$("a").hide(); // or whatever
```

Comment: @Cipi - if that's the requirement, then this probably needs a regex or such.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bookmarklet that finds all the hyperlinks and writes them to an HTML page:

javascript:ctDL=document.links;ctWI=open('','','width=400,height=300,scrollbars,resizable,menubar');ctDO=ctWI.document;ctDO.writeln('');for(ctI=0;%20ctI')}void(ctDO.close())

Answer (score 0):

It's either I don't understand the question, or it's not really that much of a challenge:

```
function findLinks(innerHTML){
    var fragment = document.createElement('div');
    fragment.innerHTML = innerHTML;

    var links = [];
    fragment.find('a').each(function(index, element){
        links.push($(element).attr('href'));
    });
    return links;
}
```